# How to externalise neo4j url to application.properites or application.yml in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to use application.yml and profiles approach for externalising db and other infrastructure dependencies.

I currently have neo4j url hard coded in the main application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.xxx.repository")
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

public Application() {
    setBasePackage("com.xxx.entity");
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

UPDATED:

```
@Value("${neo4jurl}")
private String neoUrl;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase(neoUrl);
}
```

src/main/resources/application.yml

```
neo4jurl: http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data
```

Comment: Just add it as a property to your `application.properties` and use a `@Value` annotated attribute in your class (or as method argument) to retrieve it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using application.yml, so I have changed the code to above. It works but is that the right approach?

Comment: No. Have you read my comment? You can do the same but with `application.yml` as well.

Comment: Yes I read your comment and I am doing as suggested but doesn't seem to like it. Please see the updated code.

Comment: Instead of adding it as a `@Value` on a field, add it as a method parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Do you mind explaining the real cause of this?